# Struggling with search google map places

Tags: android, dictionary, search, nullpointerexception

MapActivity

```
public class Agriculture extends AppCompatActivity implements    
       OnMapReadyCallback, 
       GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener, 
       GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

    GoogleMap mMap;
    Address address;
    LatLng latLng;
    SupportMapFragment sMapFragment;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }


public void onSearch(View view)


 {

        EditText tfLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tfLocation);

        String location = tfLocation.getText().toString();

        List<Address> addressList = null;

        if (location!=null && !location.equals(""))
        {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
            try {

                addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 0);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Address address = addressList.get(0);
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude() , address.getLongitude());
```

logcat

```
Process: amahlo.gridview, PID: 13000
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5210)
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20976)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6145)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5210) 
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20976) 
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6145) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194) 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object java.util.List.get(int)' on a null object reference
 at amahlo.gridview.Agriculture.onSearch(Agriculture.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
 at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5210) 
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20976) 
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6145) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Comment: Error is on line number 45 of `Agriculture.java`. May be your `addressList` is null. `getFromLocationName()` will returns null or empty list if no matches were found or there is no backend service available.

Comment: provide your full layout & Activity code plz

Comment: provide full code b'z you have error in onclick so there may be some thing you missing. so we can point out that.

Comment: hi all thank you for your time, i have editted and added the layout and full activity @priyankPatel i have seen that the problem is there but cannot seem to fix it please help.

Comment: The NullPointer is a side-effect of the other exception being thrown. Is that the entire logcat?

Comment: can you pl check addressList is not null and its size greater than 0 before getting the zeroth element.

Comment: @RajenRaiyarela The list variable is explicitly set to null outside the try-catch. Adding an if-statement shouldn't be a solution. A better recommendation would be moving the `addressList.get(0);` into the `try`

Comment: i m not asking to set it to null. i m asking after calling getFromLocationName  to check addressList is not null and size is greater than zero. i too have face this kind of NPE long time back when i did not receive any result for the geocoding.

Comment: @cricket_007 thank you very much i have put the addressList.get(0); into the try it works you are a Star

Comment: I mean, it "prevents" the error. I'm not sure if it completely solves your problem, though

Comment: it solves my problem and no error comes up i just need to set the map to zoom into the location searched on the map

Comment: ok the error now comes when i press the search button when the Edit text is empty

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the fact that `location` can't be `null`...

You first set the list to null.

```
List<Address> addressList = null;
```

Then continue on to check if the string is empty and do some try-catching.

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(location))
{
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
    try {
        addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However, here, if there was an exception, `addressList` is still null, therefore your error.

```
    Address address = addressList.get(0);
```

---

Without seeing the actual exception, hard to give a complete answer, but the quick solution to prevent the NullPointer is to move that last line into the `try` (and optionally check that `!addressList.isEmpty()` before attempting to access its data).